# How to make a Queries from the server in Node.js to the database OrientDB

Tags: mysql, node.js, orientdb

My question is:

- How do you make Queries from the Server to the Database?

I have been reading some articles and seeing some tutorials from Udemy about **OrientDB**, I found about what is a Query Language, like **SQL**, but I couldn't find how to send a Query from the Server to the DataBase **OrientDB** . I am making the server in **Node.js**.

I found how to start the connection and close it:

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

var server = OrientDB({
host:       'localhost',
port:       8082,  //I am using the port 8081 for Binary and 8082 for Http
username:   'root',
password:   'rootPassword'
});

server.close();
```

I have been reading the OrientDB Documents but I couldn't find it. http://orientdb.com/docs/last/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you need is just search in the official documentation

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientJS.html

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientJS-Database.html

```
var targetAvg = 0.3;
var targetTeam = 'Red Sox';

var hitters = db.query(
   'SELECT name, battavg FROM Player WHERE battavg >= :ba AND team = :team',
   {params: {
      ba: targetAvg,
      team: targetTeam
    },limit: 20 }
).then(
   function(players){
      console.log(players);
   }
);
```